# Show Users Related Record Details Without Opening Access

Tags: access, lightning-page, relatedrecord

I have what I thought would be a simple requirement to display related record fields on the account from a custom object. However, the related record component on the lightning page requires an update or create action to display those fields. For the fields to be visible I must give the users edit access in the case of the update action. I don't want the users to have the ability to edit the custom object fields. How can I display these related record fields without giving users edit access just to view them?

- The users already have read/view all access which is all we want them to have.

Answer (score 0):

Although the component relies on a Quick Action to be configured, that doesn't mean that you need to provide your users access to modify the record. There is a mention of the behaviour of this component when the users only have Read access in the documentation:

> The Related Record component typically uses quick action metadata to determine which fields to show. However, if the user viewing the component has read-only access to the related record, a compact layout is used to render the fields instead. As a result, a read-only user sees a smaller set of fields.

This means that if you create a Quick Action just for configuring this component, if the users don't have edit access they'll still have a read-only view.

Reference: [Standard Lightning Page Components](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_page_components.htm&type=5)